# How disable UAC using a Batch file + Powershell?

Tags: powershell, batch-file, uac

I had based in the following Powershell command: ([reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44409006/disabling-uac-with-powershell))

```
Set-ItemProperty -Path REGISTRY::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System -Name ConsentPromptBehaviorAdmin -Value 0
```

to disable UAC using a Batch file and i tried this sintaxe:

```
Powershell -command "& {Set-ItemProperty -Path REGISTRY::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System -Name EnableLUA -Value 0;}"
```

but nothing works. How do this correctly?

Comment: Are you running PowerShell or your batch file as an Administrator?

Comment: @TheMadTechnician, not. Very good remembered! thank you very much.